# How to downgrade Windows 10 Th2 10586 to 10586 again?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1511

I had Windows 7 Home Premium OEM on a laptop Asus K52F. Then months ago I upgraded to Windows 10 10240 build. It was good but became slow when using Chrome, etc. Well, I saw the possibility to go to the new Windows 10. But here in Brazil on 11/27/2015 it still had no upgrade, so I downloaded MediaCreationTool.exe and installed the Windows 10 Version 1511 Build 10586, codenamed Threshold 2. OK, it worked fine and fast.

On Saturday 11/28/2015, Threshold 2 began to bother me with messages: "Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item". Then I remember that I used Tweaking.com - Windows Repair software... Well, I tried to see the log, etc. I had no time so I decided to reinstall Windows 10 TH2 - here is the mess... I used some code to give me permission all files etc, but it keeps showing me that message.

I remember that I pressed F8 key (I activated), I went to something like Repair, reset windows... I'm sure I selected keep my files. I think it was like "Reset windows and keep my files...". It worked well. It kept all my files, but the installed programs weren't there anymore! Just after it I understand that reset is like reset Windows not reinstall Windows. Maybe it's my fault, but I think it needs to be clearer.

I want to downgrade Windows TH2 to Windows TH2, hehehe. Cause I have Windows.old and Windows.old(2). I tried F8 and go back to the last build, but it shows me: "We ran into a problem and won't be able to take you back to the previous build. Try resetting your current build instead. troubleshoot > reset this PC". Windows.old(2) was like empty, just like a folder and subfolder in line, not a lot. The size was like 5k... Windows.old that was a lot of files. Then I deleted Windows.old(2) to try. Did F8, restore, etc. and it gave me the same message: "We ran into..."

The question is: *I have the Windows.old with a lot of files and my software. Can I restore this Windows 10 Threshold 2 in this case?*

Comment: No;  You performed a reset, you will have to install your applications again, you were warned that would be the case.  You were told **exactly** what would happen before you proceeded.  **There is no way to "reverse" the Reset process.**

Comment: Hi,

A friend told me to do this and I am thinking:

Thank you!

"Boot from my PE recovery tools ISO (link in sig below)
/ Once booted into PE
/ Rename current "windows" folder to windows.old2
/ Rename current "windows.old" folder to "windows"
/ reboot PC" 
http://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/27180-windows-10-recovery-tools-bootable-rescue-disk.html#post434481

Comment: You can try that but I seriously doubt that will work.

Comment: @karel thank's for the corrections! I am learning!

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks but then **why did it create windows.old**? When it was W7 and turned w10 it was created. After 31 days it was deleted, OK. Then if it was created again, this is the Windows Threshold, do you agree?

Comment: Yes; The process of upgrading 10240 to Version 1511 creates a Windows.old.   Yes; Performing a Reset creates a Windows.old. No;  You cannot reverse a Reset once it is performed.